# Tool identification (Chisel )

Tags: tool-identification, chisel

I have a double bevel chisel/knife. Any information about this tool? Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fD5O.jpg)

Comment: Looks just like a carving knife, not quite a chisel since the cutting edge is orthogonal to the handle.  It might be used for making cuts at the bottom of a bowl, where the unshaped part of the blade won't cut into the sides accidentally.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen one of these before somewhere, very woolly on detail but I think it's not actually a woodworking tool. I have an inkling it's for leatherworking.

Comment: I might sound stupid. But It looks like a mini version of wood chopper or axe. : )

Comment: It looks like something my dad said was for scraping paper for erasing ink. He is not with us any longer so I cannot ask.

Comment: It is similar in form to the Abegglen woodcarving detail chisel, chip carving knives and antique cuticle trimming knives. And I too have seen similar tools used in leather working but also cannot put my finger on where. My searches have turned up a few isolated, specialty leather tools that are similar in form but nothing similar enough to proffer as an identifying match. It could be a one off original tool or modified from another though I feel that it's tidy construction and refined form suggest it was purpose made and in some number.

Comment: I'm gonna add Babbitt bearing scraper to the list of potentials though it would be a bit of an oddball as far as the forms I'm familiar with.